# CSRF not found error in laravel using VueJs

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-5.5

my home.blade file like below

```
<div id="new">
          <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" v-on:submit.prevent="addPost">
            <h4>@{{message}}</h4>
            <div class="form-group" style="padding:14px;">
              <textarea v-model="content" class="form-control" placeholder="Update your status">    </textarea><br>
              <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit">Post</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
```

and my app.js in vue like below

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#new',
    data: {
        message: 'Update New Post:',
        content: '',
    },

    methods:{

        addPost(){
            axios.post('/home/addPost', {
              content: this.content
            })
            .then(function(response) {
              console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
              console.log(error);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

and i have create a route in web.php like below

```
Route::post('addPost', 'PostController@addPost');
```

and controller like below

```
public function addPost(Request $request) {

        $content = $request->content;

        $createpost = DB::table('post')
            ->insert(['content' => $content,
                'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
                'status' => 0,

            ]);

    }
```

but in console it will give a error like below how can I make this right please help me

```
app.js:11623 CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

app.js:893 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/addPost 404 (Not Found)
Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (app.js:918)
        at settle (app.js:41630)
        at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (app.js:792)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add _token field in data if you want to send post ajax request.

```
data: {
        message: 'Update New Post:',
        content: '',
         _token: '{{csrf_token()}}'
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you can make a request to laravel, you must add csrf token to your request. The challenge when using ajax is you have to manually specify this token or else your request will not be accepted. This method currently works for me.
In your html, code add this line `<meta name="csrf_token" content ="{!!csrf_token()!!}" />`  as shown below

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My App</title>
    <meta name="csrf_token" content ="{!!csrf_token()!!}" />
```

Add this to the top of your VueJs code: You are telling Vue to include csrf token in all requests onwards

```
//App.js

 Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf_token"]').getAttribute('content'); //add token;


const app = new Vue({
    el: '#new',
    data: {
        message: 'Update New Post:',
        content: '',
    },

    methods:{

        addPost(){
            axios.post('/home/addPost', {
              content: this.content
            })
            .then(function(response) {
              console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
              console.log(error);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

store the token in a HTML meta tag

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

add this tag in  `main page`

docs : [csrf-x-csrf-token](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token)